# Sprint Reactor Filter vs IF Then

Tags: java, spring, mono, reactor

is it better to write

```
Mono.just (someVariable)
       .filter (somVariable < 5)
       .flatmap (v -> doSomeStuff (v))
       .switchIfEmpty (Mono.error (...))
```

or

```
Mono.just (someVariable)
       .flatmap (v -> { return somVariable < 5 ? doSomeStuff (v) : Mono.error (...)})
```

does it really matter or both is exactly the same but one is more "elegant"

Answer (score 0):

I would go with your first option because it filters before execute `.flatmap`.
Meaning, you will have a smaller subset of your elements.

A second argument is that the first option is more readable for me.